# Android working with MediaStore

Tags: android, gallery, mediastore

How can I open a file that I stored in gallery? I used this method to put my file there:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()
```

According to documentation it returns `String url` to the newly created file. However when I trying to open this file it fails. Getting file not found exception.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: you want to open gallery and choose image from gallery?

Comment: @Raghunandan no, I download a file. I want to save it to gallery and open it letter.

Comment: How are you accessing the URL? Are you taking the URL string and directly giving it to a File object? You should log the URL string so that you know how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the `String url` or the content uri string back. To get the actual file path from the uri you need to use something like

```
protected String convertMediaUriToPath(Uri uri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj,  null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

You can convert the string url that you get to the `Uri` using `Uri.parse(url);`

Comment: Tnx, i been on it for hours now.